# Can I send a money order from USPS as a business?

Tags: small-business, money-transfer, wire-transfer, business, money-order

I own a small business, and a contractor I hired asked to be paid through money order for services rendered.

1. Can I send a money order to him under my business? For instance,

   > ```
   > From: My business name
   > Address: My business address
   > ```
2. Domestic Money orders range from $1.20 to $1.60 does that include sending it to the recipient? (According to: https://www.usps.com/shop/money-orders.htm)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sure you can.  You can fill in whatever you want in the From section of a money order, so your business name and address would be fine.
2. The price only includes the money order itself.  You can hand deliver it yourself if you want, but if you want to mail it, you'll have to provide an envelope and a stamp.

Note that, since you won't have a bank record of this payment, you'll want to make sure you keep other records, such as the stub of the money order.  You should probably also ask the contractor to give you a receipt.

Comment: @nate-elredge Thanks. In terms of receipt he sent me an invoice, and I will be using that. My primary concern is everywhere I look online it says you require identification to send one, and as a result would I need to provide paperwork showing I own the business?

Comment: I think you only need to show ID if you are purchasing more than $3000 worth of money orders in one day.  See [12.2.2 here](http://pe.usps.com/text/dmm300/503.htm#ep1150680). Your personal ID would suffice.  In my experience they just hand you the money order with the To and From areas left blank, so you can fill them in later.  I don't think they would need to verify that what you write there matches your ID.